# Accessing a Bean Id from another Bean ID that is a class Vaadin

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans, vaadin

I have a Bean class which has an id which points to another Bean class.  For example:

```
String name;
String job;
UserLevel userlevel;
```

and the UserLevel class contains:

```
String level;
String permission;
```

So I am having trouble accessing the String level from userleve.  I created a BeanItemContainer which takes in information from a database, and I set my table's datasource to be that BeanItemContainer.  I have tried to use mytable.addContainerProperty but it did not work, I tried:

```
Firsty try: mytable.addContainerProperty("userlevel", UserLevel.class, "");
Second try: mytable.addContainerProperty("level", String.class, ""):
Thrid try: mytable.addContainerProperty("userlevel", String.class, "");
Fourth try: mytable.addContainerProperty("userlevel.level", String.class, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the addNestedContainerProperty method of your BeanItemContainer.

```
container.addNestedContainerProperty("userlevel.level");
```

You'll find more information under "Nested Properties" in this chapter of the Vaadin book: 
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.container.html

There is also the addNestedContainerBean method if you want to access all fields from UserLevel. AFAIK this method replaces the property with its subproperties.

Comment: I tried this before but it does not seem to work.  I have container properties on the table not the bean container.